# Genymotion, failed to flash files

Tags: android, genymotion

I'm currently running a windows 7. When I try to drag and drop the file that downloads the googleplay store into the device, it tells me that it has failed to flash the file to the device.

I'm currently trying to do this on a Samsung Galaxy Note 2 with the api of 18.
I would very much appreciate the help.

Comment: I've had to update both genymotion and vbox to get the drag drop flash thing working on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not using the correct zip file for the API18..

Can you please try downloading the [gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000124) file for Android 4.3 (API18) as instructed [here](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145) (Genymotion with Google Play Services).

Also remember to use the [Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip](http://filetrip.net/dl?4SUOrdcMRv) on the Genymotion emulator before flashing the gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip